# Explicitly manage Swift Package nested dependencies required?

Tags: swift, xcode11, swift-package-manager

I'm moving my Carthage libraries to Swift Package Manager. If my Swift Package has dependencies to other Swift Packages, do I have to explicitly link those libraries into the project like I do with Carthage, or are the nested dependencies embedded in the Swift Package?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a target for each dependency (if not exist) and then add them as a dependency. For example, take a look at this:

```
let package = Package(
    name: "SMUIKit",
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "SMUIKit",
            targets: ["SMUIKit"]),

        .library(
            name: "SMStyleKit",
            targets: ["SMStyleKit"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(name: "ExistDependency", url: "https://github.com/mojtabahs/ExistDependency", from: "5.0.0"),
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "SMUIKit",
            dependencies: ["SMStyleKit"]
        ),

        .target(
            name: "SMStyleKit",
            dependencies: ["ExistDependency"],
            resources: [.process("Resources")]
        ),
    ]
)
```

In this `package.swift`:

1. `SMUIKit` and `SMStyleKit` are libraries that this package creates.
2. `ExistDependency` is a package that already exists.
3. `SMUIKit` depends on the generated `SMStyleKit`.
4. `SMStyleKit` depends on the `SMStyleKit`.

I tried to cover some dependency situations but you can R&D more about how you can achieve your needs.